# set GoogleMap initial location (from gps)

Tags: android, gps, android-maps, android-maps-v2, currentlocation

I have a GoogleMap in my App. When my app starts, it finds out the current position via gps and changes the map to this position. If my app was already started before and the initial position was changed, then I want to keep this user selected position and don´t want my map to change again to the current gps-position.

Is there a better way than this?

```
private final CameraPosition cameraPositionNull = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(0.0,0.0),2f, 0f,0f);
if (map.getCameraPosition().equals(cameraPositionNull)) {
    ...
}
```

Greetings, masrlinu

Comment: you may save the position in some preference file, and restore it in onResume() method. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way also:

```
   mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 0));
```

Comment: Your solution always moves the map to the new coordinates, but I just want to change the coordinates, if the user did not change them manually before.

Comment: I have the current location, but I just want to set it, if the user did not change the position manually.